# React-native Component with specific layout overwriting the layout of application

Tags: android, react-native, recyclerlistview, flash-list

I'm developing an app that is RTL, is there a way to make a component's layout LTR no matter the layout direction of the whole app?

the reason i'm trying to achieve this is there is an issue with `@shopify/flash-list` and `recyclerlistview` packages, both regarding RTL direction, they work fine in LTR but the lists have varying bugs in RTL mode.

React-native's `View` can be given the styling of `style={{direction: "ltr"}}` which does not work.

I'm wondering if something like this can be achieved:

```
<CustomLayout dir="ltr">
  {children}
 </CustomLayout>
```